# Show a Java applet on clicking on HTML Text elements

Tags: jquery, html, applet

I am trying to make a jquery plugin for which the description is given below. I haven't had much experience working in jQuery so I really needed some help.

Here is the Java Applet I am talking about http://www.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk/dasher/TryJavaDasherNow.html

The applet does some operation the result is shown in the text box in the applet.

[image]

Consider a virtual keyboard which comes up when the user clicks on a text box or a text area element. 
For eg:
[image]

Similarly, I wanted that the applet should appear when the user clicks on TextBox/TextArea element and after some operations, the result in the applet text box should go into the html text element. 
I hope I am able to make myself clear. Please help me regarding this. I haven't been working with jQuery but this can be done with its use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your applet id is `id="myapplet"` Give it the style `display:hidden` so it's initially hidden. Place it anywhere in your HTML where you want it to appear when user clicks  on a `TEXTAERA` or text `INPUT`.

```
<object id="myapplet" style="display:none;">......</object>
```

Then with jQuery you can do

```
$('textarea, input').click(function(){
$('#myapplet').show();
});
```

This will show the applet when you click `TEXTAREA` or `INPUT`.

**Update**
As per your comment below, if you want to open the applet over the page where user can drag it around, you can use jQuery's UI dialog function. Read more at http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

First Put your java object inside an HTML file and name it applet.html. No need to have `display:none` on your object. Then you can do

```
$('textarea, input').click(function() {
    var $div = $('<div title="Java Applet"></div>');
    $div.load('applet.html', function() {
        $div.dialog({autoOpen: false});
    });
});
```

Remember to include the JS and CSS files for jQuery UI in addition to jQuery.

Place this in your head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

and place those before closing body tag

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Hussein, 
Thanks for the reply. Actaully that solved one of my problem.
Consider this situation, when the person clicks on the input element, the virtual keuyboard popsup but this actually isn't embedded in the webpage. It comes up when over the webpage as in this figure.
http://i.imgur.com/7CDk4.jpg
  Similarly is with this applet. It is not there embedded in the webpage but should appear over the webpage

Comment: I'll try this when I'll be back home and also ask if I face any problems. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I was trying to find a PM option on these forums or for that matter your email, but looks like your webcarts id one is not working. Can you please update the address.

Comment: I edited my original post for for just some help regarding the jQuery plguin. Can you please check it? Thanks